# Auto Populate Access Form using simple VBA code by setting a variable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was recently given the task of creating a form that will autofill with the information from a table. The information the form autofills is selected using a primary key called ModID. I have a combo box that has a List of the ModIDs that are listed as Active.

```
SELECT ModID
FROM P_Review
WHERE Status = "Active"
```

Simple enough. I then have VBA code running on the event After Update. So after the value for the combo box is select or changed it will run this VBA code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub selectModID_AfterUpdate()
    'Find the record that matches the control.
On Error GoTo ProcError
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    With rs
            .FindFirst "ModID=" & Me.selectModID
            If Not .NoMatch Then
                Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
            Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    Me!localModID = Me.selectModID.Column(0)

            End If
    End With

ExitProc:
    Exit Sub
ProcError:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitProc

End Sub
```

The code runs fine (I get no errors when I debug or run).

Now for the access text box. I would like to populate certain fields based off the variable localModID. I have a dlookup in a text box to find the information in the table P_Review.

```
=DLookUp("Threshold","P_Review","ModID =" & [localModID])
```

So the DlookUp should find the value for the column threshold, in the table P_Review, where the ModID in P_Review equals the localModID set in the VBA code. But when I go to form view and select a ModID I get the Error 3070: The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize  as a valid field name or expression. I did copy this code from another database we are already using but it fails in this new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub ModID_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rs As Object

   Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
   With rs
      .FindFirst "ModID='" & Me.ModID & "'"
   If Not .NoMatch Then
      Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark

   Else
      DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
      Me!ModID = Me.ModID
   End If
   End With

End Sub
```

This is the answer to question. I used this code to auto update.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Forms!<whatever_this_form_name_is>![localModID]
```

in your DLOOKUP

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention it in my question, but I tried this and it returns the same error message.